# Propagate Tags AWS EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

I'm using Terraform to deploy my infrastructure, and i would like to know if there is a way to propagate my EKS tags to any resources that it create (EC2, SG, ELB, EBS...) ?

for the the moment i use this in Terraform to tag all my resources :

```
default_tags {
    tags = {
      Environment = "Prod"
      Project     = "my project"
    }
```

But all the resources created by EKS, or by the node groups are not tagged with those.
Someone know how to manage this ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a map variable called tags and refer to that variable in any resource you want to add those tags in.

```
variable "global_tags" {
  description = "A mapping of tags to assign to multiple aws resources"
  default     = {}
}
global_tags = {
    Terraform_Managed = "true"
    Environment = "prod"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this will not work for every resources created by EKS.